# How can I get everything off the wifi?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have moved into a house that has... interesting wiring decisions.

There are cable ports in:

- A - The Living Room
- B - My Wife's Office

And in C - My Office, there is an ethernet & phone port (who's cables are visible in the basement, but cut and disconnected).

I would like for the ports in my wife's office and my office to effectively 'hard-wire' us to the router, which is currently set up in the living room because the most devices needing a hard connection are there.

Currently the internet comes into the house in the basement and gets split into 3 paths (One to A, one to B, and one to nothing).

What all equipment and changes do I need to make in order to have the internet hard-wired in all of these locations? Can I do so without any extra cable-running (other than of course the ethernet-cable connection, since I will have to refit those wires)?

I tried simply connecting her PC to the port in the wall, but that did nothing. I'm assuming that's because that connection goes into the splitter and heads back out of the house, and there's no router in-between managing traffic.

---

For more information on the connections/wiring:

Coaxial Cable from road -> Basement -> Splitter

- Split A -> Coaxial Cable Living Room -> Wireless Router for the house
- Split B -> Coaxial Cable to wall port in wife's office -> Cable Modem -> Wife's PC
- Split C -> Coaxial Cable to nothing (Hopefully able to connect this to the loose ethernet wires for my office)

Comment: It sounds like you already have the network you want.  What exactly isn't working with your current setup?

Comment: When I connect my wife's PC to the cable port in her office, the router is unreachable as is the internet.

I know there aren't issues with the wires themselves because if i set up the router in her office, i get an internet connection from there.

Comment: Also, @Ramhound, I am assuming I can connect the ethernet port to the 'nothing' cable, but do I need a modem there is there some sort of simple cable conversion i can do?

Comment: You have to provide us information how those ports are connected specifically.  What type of cable is being used?  What you have provided so far isn't detailed enough.

Comment: @Ramhound I added more info to the question. Thank you and if you need more info please just comment :)

Comment: What?  What does coaxial cables have to do with CAT 5 Ethernet cables?  If you cannot connect the cable modem to Split B then Split B isn't connected to the same source as Split A.  You are going to have to run Ethernet throughout the house to achieve what you want, you currently, do not have that.